# Kde neon stuck/freeze on boot after installing nvidia driver

Tags: kde, nvidia, kde-neon

I am new to linux and KDE. I just tried installing NVIDIA proprietary driver, and reboot. After I reboot, KDE neon would display grub as usual and I chose KDE neon, after that the loading appear and then my laptop manufacturer's name is showed and stuck right there, nothing happens, SDDM doesn't appear. My questions are why is this happening ? What should I do then if I want to install NVIDIA driver ? Is it true that that happens because the driver is not compatible with the kernel ? because I notice that KDE neon did a firmware update recently. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Some info :

OS : KDE neon User Edition 5.18 64bit

Kernel : 5.3.0-42-generic

CPU : Intel i5-4210U

GPU : NVIDIA Geforce 920M

Driver that I've tried : nvidia-390 and nvidia-440

Please let me know if I have to provide another information, thank you. sorry for the broken english too.

Comment: I don't know much about KDE Neon but I believe it runs on KWin which is based on Wayland. In my own experience latest NVIDIA non free drivers do not play well with Wayland. However the open source Nouveau drivers work very well with Wayland. You can try to run KDE Neon on X11 with the proprietary drivers. To fix your issue you can uninstall the NVIDIA drivers through a TTY.

Comment: Thank you for your comment sir. Yeah, i have tried logging in using TTY, but TTY acts strangely, it blinks/flash/refreshing every 1 or 2 seconds, therefore i can't enter my password in time. So my only choice is to clean install it.

Comment: Also, does it mean that I shouldn't use KDE if i want to use NVIDIA driver ? Because I really need that driver.

Comment: I don't know how difficult is to tinker KDE to make it run on X, but sure if you want a system compatible with NVIDIA drivers out of the box, yes, you should try something else than KDE. With GNOME it's easy to choose to run on X or on Wayland at startup.

Comment: Have a look at this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/7zn555/what_is_the_recommended_solution_for_nvidia/) you mind find a solution to make your config work on KDE.

Comment: Thank you sir for answering. I just gave up with KDE neon and changing back to Ubuntu now.